# Call to a member function getCLientOriginalExtension() on null using Laravel

Tags: laravel

I am trying to update only input field text but don't want to update the image when I submit on the button. Unfortunately, I face an error.

The error is:

> Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError
> Call to a member function getCLientOriginalExtension() on null

The error is visible here: https://flareapp.io/share/v5pQ6xmE#F44

**Controller**

```
                     public function updateoffer(Request $request,$id)
                     {

                      $offer_name=$request->get('offername');
                      $image=$request->file('offer_image');
                      $extension=$image->getCLientOriginalExtension();
                      Storage::disk('cms')->put($image- 
                      >getFileName().'.'.$extension,File::get($image));
                      $content = new Offers();
                      $content->image=$image->getFilename() . '.' . $extension;
                      $check=Offers::where('id',$id)- 
                      >update(['offer_name'=>$offer_name,'offer_image'=>$content->image]);
                      return back()->with('success','Successfully Updated',$check);
                       }
```

Comment: Can you please update the question with form code.

Comment: It also looks like `getCLientOriginalExtension()` has a case error in it too (second letter should be lower case).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your file option in the HTML form is optional. So, you can check if a file exists using [`hasFile`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/requests#retrieving-uploaded-files) in Laravel.

```
<?php

public function updateoffer(Request $request,$id){
  $offer_name = $request->get('offername');

  if($request->hasFile('offer_image')){
    $image = $request->file('offer_image');
    $extension = $image->getCLientOriginalExtension();
    Storage::disk('cms')->put($image->getFileName().'.'.$extension,File::get($image));
    $content = new Offers();
    $content->image=$image->getFilename() . '.' . $extension;
    $check = Offers::where('id',$id)->update(['offer_name'=>$offer_name,'offer_image'=>$content->image]);
  }else{
    $check = Offers::where('id',$id)->update(['offer_name'=>$offer_name]);
  }


  return back()->with('success','Successfully Updated',$check);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to check image have or not

```
public function updateoffer(Request $request,$id)
{
 // Create New Intance For Update
 $content = new Offers();

 // Get Name
 $offer_name=$request->get('offername');

 // Get Image If It Exists
 if ($request->hasFile('offer_image')) {

  $image=$request->file('offer_image');

  $extension=$image->getCLientOriginalExtension();

  Storage::disk('cms')->put($image->getFileName().'.'.$extension,File::get($image));

  $content->image=$image->getFilename() . '.' . $extension;
  } else {
   $content->image = null;
   // if database not accept null you can send empty ''
   // $content->image = ''; 
  }

 $check=Offers::where('id',$id)->update([
  'offer_name'=>$offer_name,
  'offer_image'=>$content->image
 ]);

 return back()->with('success','Successfully Updated',$check);

}
```

Hope it help :)